# Is it possible to tweak the server time from Java/Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date

My Spring boot jar file will be running on different platforms and on different machines. Some of those machines often have time that does not correspond to the remote server this jar communicates with. What I'd like to maintain is an internal clock for Spring so that every time I call new Date(), it returns the current time of that internal clock, and not the machine's current time.

This probably has a very simple solution of some kind, but I haven't been able to come up with anything other than this: extending Date class, and appending the current remote server time as a default to the constructor. I however don't believe this is the best way to do this.

How I can configure any internal clock or the embedded tomcat server time?

Comment: If your system is using Java 8 you could try to implement your own [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html)

Comment: Do you need to change only Time Zone for your application or you need to have completely new Date?

Comment: @M.leRutte Is it compatible with java.util.Date?

Comment: @MonteCristo I don't need to configure the time zone, rather I would like the local machines to adjust to server time. e.g. Let's say a transaction takes place @ 6:00 clock in the server time. But on the client's pc, it's only 5:51. I am looking to have the former time available to me. I have a rest endpoint which returns the server time.

Comment: With a few steps you can create a `java.util.Date` from it. See the [Oracle Trail on `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Comment: Instead of adjusting the client machine application time itself, implement a `created` field or similar for each of the entities you're interested in and make the server populate it when the transaction is made. Then you don't need the client to set that value.

Comment: This is basically an intermediary service so it doesn't contain any form of client interaction. However, can you still elaborate on how you mean I handle the created field? @XtremeBiker

Comment: You tell about changing the `new Date()` result for clients in some way. I suggest you accessing the server API and retrieving the time instead. The question is, what you're using `new Date()` for?

Comment: @XtremeBiker accessing server API everytime is an overhead that I'd very much like to avoid. I am using new Date() to set the exact time the event has occurred at, would very much like to ensure that my results are not dependent on the client's machine.